# Why do I get expected expression before 'int16_t' error in C?

Tags: c, unions

I am working with the function

```
int max30205_write_trip_low_thyst(float temperature)//, I2C &i2c_bus)
{
    max30205_raw_data raw;
    temperature /= MAX30205_CF_LSB;
    raw.swrd = int16_t(temperature); // here -> expected expression before 'int16_t'
    return max30205_write_reg16(raw.swrd, MAX30205_REG_THYST_LOW_TRIP);//, i2c_bus);
}
```

and when I try to compile I get the following error
`expected expression before 'int16_t'`

Why is this?

looking the header file I see that

```
#define MAX30205_CF_LSB           (0.00390625F)

typedef union max30205_raw_data {
    struct {
        uint8_t lsb;
        uint8_t msb;
    };
    struct {
        uint16_t magnitude_bits:15;
        uint16_t sign_bit:1;
    };
    uint16_t uwrd;
    int16_t swrd;
} max30205_raw_data;
```

Comment: The syntax for conversion is `(sometype)somevalue`. In your case `(int16_t)temperature`

Comment: Strange. The code is very much C, but that cast is C++ only syntax. I wonder who wrote that.

Comment: The relevant [C11 Standard 6.5.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4)

Answer (score 4):

Because `int16_t(temperature);` is not valid C syntax. You need to do `(int16_t)temperature`.

Comment: I am going to add basic, but important information to the answer, it is called variable casting and that is how you make it